# jquery show, trying to show element with the same class

Tags: jquery, css

I have several buttons `.modif` with an attribute title, different for each, for example `:
title="one"`, then all the boxes have the same class `.box_slide`, but I'm trying to show just the one who has also the class box_one and hide the others, all the boxes had the class `.box_slide`

the thing is that all the boxes are hiding, can someone show me a better way to do this.

```
$('.modif').click(function (){    
    var title = $(this).attr('title'); 
    $('.box_slide').hide();
    $('.box_' + title).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning in your description that the title is "box_one". But in code, you are putting it as

```
 $('.box_' + title).show();
```

This will result as box_box_one

Hence This might be causing the issue.

Below would work as expected

```
$('.box_slide.box' + title).show();
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the title is just 'one'

Comment: So in that case that particular element only has a class as box_one?

Comment: each gores like this:

 class="box_slide box_one"

 class="box_slide box_two"

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
$('.box_' + title).show();
```

by this:

```
$('.box_slide[title=box_' + title + ']').show();
```

Comment: Please try this: $('.box_slide[title=' + title + ']').show();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Attribute Starts With Selector \[name^="value"\]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to show all elements that has class beginning with box_ and hide the specific one:

```
$('.modif').click(function (){    
    $("[class^='box_']").show();
    $('.box_slide').hide();
});
```

Comment: OP is not looking for all elements but one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the following should work

```
$('.modif').click(function (){    
    var title = $(this).attr('title'); 
    $('.box_slide').hide();
    $('.box_slide .' + title).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$('.modif').click(function (){    
    var title = $(this).attr('title'); 
    $('.box_slide').hide();
    $('.box_' + title ).show();
});
```

Comment: I edit my answer, the title it's just 'one', but still not working

Comment: seems like any other method is overriding it. Can you paste some of the html ?